# Stack Exchange site "Gaming" featured in The Faster Times

Tags: discussion, publicity

[Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) is featured in a [The Faster Times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faster_Times) article from yesterday, in the venture capital section:

[Can Stack Overflow Do for Gaming What it Did for Programming?](http://thefastertimes.com/venturecapital/2010/07/15/can-stack-overflow-do-for-gaming-what-it-did-for-programming/)

*"So Stack has launched gaming.stackexchange.com  to bring the magic that exists on StackOverflow to the gaming vertical.*"

*"Our portfolio company Stack Overflow is attempting to change that."*

What does the last quote mean?

Comment: Not a great increase in traffic though, I guess gamers don't read VC columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last quote seems to imply that The Faster Times is one of the venture capitalists backing up the new Stack Exchange 2.0. Additionally, the article itself is in the Venture Capital section. As well, it means that ideally, the Gaming site will succeed in bringing expert knowledge in a noise-reduced site for people to easily find the solutions they need to gaming problems.

Great to see our name promoted like that! Glad to see that our community isn't the only one who wants to see this site succeed!

Comment: ☢ ☢ **Okuu** ☢ ☢